# How to use google scripts to check two google sheets, and move the duplicates to a new sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do something which seems simple. I have a gigantic sheet of 20k contacts, and there are contacts with bad emails. I've compiled a list of the bad emails I want to pull, and want to write a script which finds the emails from the "bad" list in the "20k" list, copies the whole row of each bad email to a "new" (generated) sheet, and then delete the row from the list of 20k.

Everything works until it needs to check for duplicates, copy them and delete the old ones (a nested for loop). Right now it copies everything (duplicate or not)multiple times, and then deletes the entire sheet. Here is the problem code:

```
 // Find duplicates from the two sheets and move them to the "FindDupes" sheet
  var dupes = false;
  var dataMDS = sourceSheetMDS.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataETR = sourceSheetETR.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i = numETRRows; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (j = numMDSRows; j >= 0; j--) {
      if  (sourceSheetETR[i,1] == sourceSheetMDS[j,1]) {
        dupes = true;

        // Copy the desired rows to the FindDupes sheet
        for (var k = 1; k <= numMDSCols; k++) {
          var sourceRange = sourceSheetMDS.getRange(1,k,j);
          var nextCol = newSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
          sourceRange.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1,nextCol,j));
        }
        sourceSheetMDS.deleteRow(j);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the whole project:

```
function findDuplicates() {

  // List the columns you want to check by number (A = 1)
  var CHECK_COLUMNS = [1];

  //Declare the Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  // Get the active sheet and info about it
  // Main Database Sheet
  var sourceSheetMDS = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var numMDSRows = sourceSheetMDS.getLastRow();
  var numMDSCols = sourceSheetMDS.getLastColumn();

  // Get the active sheet and info about it
  // Emails To Rremove Sheet
  var sourceSheetETR = ss.getSheetByName("Emails to Remove");
  var numETRRows = sourceSheetETR.getLastRow();
  var numETRCols = sourceSheetETR.getLastColumn();

  // Create the sheet of duplicates
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet("FindDupes");

  // Find duplicates from the two sheets and move them to the "FindDupes" sheet
  var dupes = false;
  var dataMDS = sourceSheetMDS.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataETR = sourceSheetETR.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i = numETRRows; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (j = numMDSRows; j >= 0; j--) {
      if  (sourceSheetETR[i,1] == sourceSheetMDS[j,1]) {
        dupes = true;

        // Copy the desired rows to the FindDupes sheet
        for (var k = 1; k <= numMDSCols; k++) {
          var sourceRange = sourceSheetMDS.getRange(1,k,j);
          var nextCol = newSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
          sourceRange.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1,nextCol,j));
        }
        sourceSheetMDS.deleteRow(j);
      }
    }
  }


  // Alert the user with the results
  if (dupes) {
    Browser.msgBox("Possible duplicate(s) found, moved, and deleted.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found.");
  }
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with your code - is it not working as expected, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I edited it to show what the problem code is, and what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change a few things around because I couldn't get it to run properly.

```js
function findDuplicates() {

  // List the columns you want to check by number (A = 1)
  var CHECK_COLUMNS = [1];

  //Declare the Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  // Get the active sheet and info about it
  // Main Database Sheet
  var sourceSheetMDS = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var numMDSRows = sourceSheetMDS.getLastRow();
  var numMDSCols = sourceSheetMDS.getLastColumn();

  // Get the active sheet and info about it
  // Emails To Rremove Sheet
  var sourceSheetETR = ss.getSheetByName("Emails to Remove");
  var numETRRows = sourceSheetETR.getLastRow();
  var numETRCols = sourceSheetETR.getLastColumn();
  
  // Create the sheet of duplicates
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet("FindDupes");

  // Find duplicates from the two sheets and move them to the "FindDupes" sheet
  var dupes = false;
  var dataMDS = sourceSheetMDS.getDataRange().getValues().reverse();
  var dataETR = sourceSheetETR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rowsToDelete = []
  dataETR.forEach(function (emailToRemoveRow) {
    var emailToRemove = emailToRemoveRow[0]
    dataMDS.forEach(function (dataRow, j) {
      var emailOfData = dataRow[0]
      if (emailToRemove == emailOfData) {
        dupes = true;

        // Copy the desired rows to the FindDupes sheet
        newSheet.appendRow(dataRow)
        rowsToDelete.push(j)
      }
    })
  })
  rowsToDelete.sort(function (a, b) {
   return b - a;
  }).forEach(function (rowIndex) {
     sourceSheetMDS.deleteRow(rowIndex);
  })


  // Alert the user with the results
  if (dupes) {
    Browser.msgBox("Possible duplicate(s) found, moved, and deleted.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found.");
  }
};
```

and I am still a little confused because check_columns is not getting used. So where exactly is the email column? And what does the emails to remove sheet looks like? This code above is assuming that the email to remove sheet only has a single column which has the emails we want to remove, and the test sheet has the emails in its first column.

Comment: Not to sound redundant, but thanks so much! The check_column should be used for the Main Data Base sheet. In the original code the check_columns would take the place of where 1 is found (for the MDS). That way, if I need to check for names as duplicates I could could easily change it to that column. The emails to remove sheet just has one column which has a big list of emails, where as the big data base has a ton of columns, but only needs one specific column to be checked.

Comment: Ok. Well that shouldn't be too hard to add. Did this script work for you?

Comment: I agree, that will be a small tweak. It seems to be so freaking close!! Is there a way to check it from bottom to top? It keeps tripping an error saying that it is out of bounds: Those rows are out of bounds. (line 38, file "Code"). When I debug the code it says that j is equal to value zero.

Comment: Ok i tweaked it so it will check it bottom up (reverse()). But also added a few lines to sort the rows to delete so that they get removed bottom up as well. I think that should fix the out of bounds error but there still might be a bug.

Comment: You're a freaking superhero. It does almost everything. For some reason it only imports every other one, deletes non-duplicates, and then still goes out of bounds at the end. I'm trying to tweak this as you are sending it over, but I've never seen the strategies you use!

Comment: It is hard to debug without having more example data. In my really basic spreadsheet it seems to work properly.

Comment: I completely understand. I'm probably inputting it wrong. I'm going to mark this as good. Thank you so much! Can I give you some a few dollars for food as a sign of thanks?

Comment: Definitely don't want any money. But I can try to help out more to get it working properly.

Comment: Well then I hope my profound appreciation is enough! Can I share the project with you via message? The contacts are sensitive for the public, but sharing with you will be just fine.

Comment: yes I would definitely take a look and see if I can figure it out more.

Comment: Fantastic, I don't have enough points to chat, so here is my email address: forethinkersfire@gmail.com. I can send you the sheets from there. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if  (sourceSheetETR[i,1] == sourceSheetMDS[j,1]) {
        dupes = true;
...
```

to

```
if  (dataETR[i,1] == dataMDS[j,1]) {
        dupes = true;
...
```

Explanation:

You have to compare values and not (not existant) sheet array entries.

Comment: Thanks for responding, seriously means a lot. I made the change, but now it says no duplicates are found. I don't have a ton of money, but if you help me crack this I'd love to send you twenty bucks to get a bite or something.

Comment: I am kinda confused. What is the point of the CHECK_COLUMNS variable? It doesn't seem to be getting used.

Comment: The check columns variable is supposed to make it easier to specify which columns get checked. That way if I am checking emails for duplicates, then I can specify the email column, if I want to check for names then I can specify that one.